# Issue of Compability view and trusted sites IE 11 on Windows 20H2

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We have a production website using ActiveX and running on Internet Explorer (IE) 5-6-7-8.

From IE11 we need to add website URL to compability view for using

Our production website working normal with IE11 on all windows version older than version 20H2

After upgrade to Windows 20H2 (19042.928), we have an issue:

- If the website url is domain (http://erp.company.com:8080) then it's OK. The login form can load ActiveX control and show 02 button "Create shortcut on desktop" and "Set as start page",[image]
- If the website url is ip address (http://192.168.1.100:8080), our website cannot load ActiveX and show 02 button "Create shortcut on desktop" and "Set as start page" then cannot login.
  And I can add duplicate IP address on Trusted Site as image >> it's wrong
  [image]

[image]

Please help me.
Thank you.

P/S: I have just tried with Administrator account, no problem with Administrator account.
I think this problem related with permission to access registry but I don't know exactly.

Comment: Please clarify the second bullet-point - the text is confusing, and you should also include the error that you're getting with an IP address.

Comment: Have you tried Chromium Edge? There are no more sites or network devices I needed IE for because Chromium Edge works with everything now.

Comment: I have edit my post.
I have tried on Chronium Edge with IE mode, and the problem is the same with IE

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that IE11 has not received any significant updates in any recent feature update.  If the problem works with the built-in Administrator then this most likely is a system configuration issue unrelated to 20H2 directly.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has formally announced the death of Internet Explorer. June 2022

You now have to change sites that use IE tools to run instead to use Chromium Edge to run.

The situation for using Internet Explorer is now formally hopeless.

[Death of IE](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-announces-the-official-end-of-internet-explorer/?ftag=TREe01923b&bhid=23164040498209351948461508422926&mid=13373375&cid=712212189)

> It's been a long time coming, but Microsoft has finally announced the
> official end of life date for Internet Explorer: June 15, 2022. A blog
> post by Microsoft's Sean Lyndersay, partner group manager for
> Microsoft Edge, spells out the specifics of IE's official demise, with
> plans to transition everyone to Microsoft's newer Chromium-based
> browser, Edge.